# PHP: Generate unique random int number based on an id

Tags: php

I'm currently searching for a good way to generate a unique random number for SEPA transactions (End-to-End reference) with 27 digits in PHP. My requirements are:

- Must be unique
- Only int values, no letters
- Length of 27 digits
- Use an user id and time to make the ID unique

I've tried this solution here but this only gives me a string with letters and numbers:

```
md5( uniqid( mt_rand(), true ) );
```

Does anyone has a lightweight solution or idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $bira = date('YmdHis').rand(1000000000000,9000000000000);
echo "<br/>";
echo strlen($bira);
```

Add the time stamp in the front, so it will be unique always.

OR `echo $bira = time().rand(10000000000000000,90000000000000000);`

outoput:

> 201901220142532979656312614
>
> 27

Comment: I don't know if this is really "unique". Are you sure that it's unique? Forever and ever?

Comment: Once times goes, never come back. that is timestamp :)

Comment: I think what he's asking is whether there's a chance of collision. But there shouldn't be.

Comment: You can use a combination of a unique id (say user_id) in your database + unique_timestamp to create a unique number.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$array = [];
$numberOfTransactions = 1;

while (count($array) < $numberOfTransactions) {
    $rand = mt_rand(100000000000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999999999);
    $array[$rand] = $rand;
}

print_r($array);
```

Associative array keys are unique, so you won't get any duplicates.

Comment: This is a good idea. I'll wait some minutes but I think your idea is great!

Comment: Array ( [] => ) mt_rand() expects parameter 1 to be integer, float given on line 5

Answer (score 0):

To get a 27-digit integer, you can take the first 27 characters of the hexadecimal hash and convert it to an integer.

try this:

```php
function generateUniqueRandomInt($userId) {
    $uniqueString = $userId . uniqid('', true); // Concatenate user ID and unique ID
    $hashedString = hash('sha256', $uniqueString); // Generate SHA-256 hash
    $first27Digits = substr($hashedString, 0, 27); // Take the first 27 characters
    $uniqueNumber = (int) $first27Digits; // Convert to integer

    return str_pad($uniqueNumber, 27, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // Pad with leading zeros if needed
}
```

You can use this function to generate a unique random integer number with 27 digits:

```php
$userID = 12345; // Replace with the actual user ID
$uniqueRandomNumber = generateUniqueRandomInt($userID);
echo $uniqueRandomNumber;
```